# The mother helping her baby walks by holding her baby hands

Tags: sentence-construction

[image]

> The mother helping her baby walks by **holding** her baby hands.
>   Come, let me **hold** you.

What is the verb that should be used? Hold?

Comment: "helping" should be changed to "is helping" and "walks" should be changed to "walk" and last "baby" should be changed to "baby's". Rest are okay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The verb *hold* can be used in both cases, although *holding hands* is much different then *holding you*.

If a mother was talking to her child while the child was learning to walk, the mother might say:

> Let me hold your hands to help you.

or:

> Let me help you by holding your hands.

(No difference in meaning.)

However, you also ask about:

> *Let me hold you.*

When I hear that, I usually expect a parent to hold a toddler something like this:

[image] [image] [image] [image]

The verb *hold* is rather versatile, in that it can mean to embrace, to grasp, or to pick up and carry.

If you were going to hold the child's hand, you wouldn't say, "Come, let me hold you." Instead, you'd say, "Come, let me hold your hand."

Answer (score 2):

Man from India's  corrections are indeed needed. However, as to the verb: the first instance of "holding" is good, but the latter instance "let me hold you" is not quite right, because "holding" a baby (picking him up in your arms) is not the same as holding his hands. So it's either " Come, let me help you." or" Come, let me hold your hand(s)."

Answer (score 1):

> The mother helping her baby walks by holding her baby hands.

The use of the verb **to hold** is okay in the first sentence. For the second sentence, refer to Brian Hitchock's answer.

But as *Man_From_India* has said, you should use **is** before **helping** and **walk** instead of **walks** and **baby's** instead of **baby** if your intended meaning is

> The baby is walking with her mother's help.

Like this:

> The mother **is** helping her baby **walk** by holding her **baby's** hands.

If you leave your first sentence as it is, it would be okay grammaticaly but could be understood to mean

> The mother, who helps her baby, is walking with her baby's help (by holding her "baby hands").
>   The mother [(who is) helping her baby] walks by holding her [baby hands]

Comment: Nice explanation of that wrong sentence. Actually that sentence is wrong in that that is not a complete sentence and the meaning that sentence convey is not the intended meaning. Nice explanation :)

Comment: @Man_From_India Dropping *is* is fine..if the image is illustrative. The mother holding her baby with its hands -for instance!

Comment: @MaulikV right, but dropping "is" will make it a part of a sentence, not a complete sentence. You can use that form for a caption of an image as you mentioned, for a title etc

Comment: @Man_From_India that's what I said... a caption for the image illustrating it. That's what it seemed first when I saw the lady's picture! :)